# How to normalize data for VGG-16 pretrained model?

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, convolution

I can't really find any data on how to go about normalizing the input for the following VGG-16 model I am using https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3

Right now I am inputting a black and white image (copied 3 times to make it compatible).  I have the colors normalized between 0 and 1.  I am not sure if this is correct for VGG-16.  Is the VGG model expecting mean - std normalization?  Or does it not really matter?

Comment: You should have 3 color channels RGB. In the code author subtract mean from each channel (103, 116 and 123)

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, itdxer writes

> You should have 3 color channels RGB. In the code author subtract mean from each channel (103, 116 and 123).